# DB2 Group by specific columns

Tags: db2-luw

| ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 | LANG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | F_lang |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | null |
| 2 | 22 | 222 | null |

Is it possible to build  a query which returns only these two lines below.
It should be grouped by the first three columns and should take only that line with value of column `LANG` which is preferably not null, if no value for `LANG` exists, it should take the line with language null.

| ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 | LANG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | F_lang |
| 2 | 22 | 222 | null |

Comment: `SELECT ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, MAX (LANG) AS LANG FROM MYTAB GROUP BY ID_1, ID_2, ID_3`. The question is what would you like to get on more than 1 non-null LANGs for a single group like `(1, 11, 111, 'F_lang1'), (1, 11, 111, 'F_lang2')`?

Comment: It should be return both rows, meaning `F_lang1` and `F_lang2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this anwser the question ?

```
with t1(id_1, id_2, id_3, lang) as (
  VALUES
  ('1', '11', '111', 'F_lang'),
  ('1', '11', '111', NULL),
  ('2', '22', '222', NULL),
  ('3', '33', '333', 'F_lang_3_1'),
  ('3', '33', '333', 'F_lang_3_2'),
  ('3', '33', '333', NULL)
)
select id_1, id_2, id_3, lang from t1 where lang is not null
union all
select id_1, id_2, id_3, null as lang from t1 group by id_1, id_2, id_3 having max(lang) is null
order by id_1, id_2, id_3
```

| ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 | LANG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | F_lang |
| 2 | 22 | 222 | *null* |
| 3 | 33 | 333 | F_lang_3_1 |
| 3 | 33 | 333 | F_lang_3_2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BJRgmRw8)

Comment: It is working, but what do this `having max(lang)` is null?

Comment: It selects groups where max(lang) is null that is where all lang are null

Answer (score 0):

Using OLAP count function.
`cnt = 0` means: there are no non-null langs in the group.

```
with t1(id_1, id_2, id_3, lang) as (
  VALUES
  ('1', '11', '111', 'F_lang'),
  ('1', '11', '111', NULL),
  ('2', '22', '222', NULL),
  ('3', '33', '333', 'F_lang_3_1'),
  ('3', '33', '333', 'F_lang_3_2'),
  ('3', '33', '333', NULL)
)
select id_1, id_2, id_3, lang
from
(
select 
  id_1, id_2, id_3, lang
, count (lang) over (partition by id_1, id_2, id_3) cnt
from t1
)
where lang is not null or cnt = 0
order by id_1, id_2, id_3
```

| ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 | LANG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | F_lang |
| 2 | 22 | 222 |  |
| 3 | 33 | 333 | F_lang_3_1 |
| 3 | 33 | 333 | F_lang_3_2 |